# 2012 Volkswagen Passat se Drivers side heat actuator?

Tags: vw, heat, actuator

I drive a 2012 Volkswagen Passat, SE and my driver side heat does not work but my passenger side does. I scanned my car for issues and it said drivers side actuator but i can’t figure out where it is, so where is the left heat actuator?

Comment: My guess is the actuator is a relay (87A type). Check all  fuse panels and refer to your owner's manual or try online for manufacturers owner's manual. If you locate the driver and passenger seat heater relays, swap them to see if the relay is at fault. Most likely the heating element broke (more use of driver's seat than passenger seat), verified with a continuity test using a multimeter. If the element is broken, the seat will need to be removed and disassembled to find the damage before a repair is made.